# Access values of individual items in an enum

Tags: rust

I have a program as follows

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum A {
    A,
    y {
        C: i32,
        P: i32,
    },
}
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let p = A::y { C: 0, P: 0 };
    println!("{:?}", p);
}
```

I want to read the value of `c` and assign it to a variable
How to read the value `c`

Comment: You need something like `match p { A::y { C: c, ..} => c }` or the equivalent `if let` expression. You can't extract the field unconditionally, since the enum might be `A::A` as well.

Comment: As a side note, enum variants should use UpperCamelCase and struct fields should be snake_case.